# Sending command to Network printer IP from https pages

Tags: http, ssl, printing, https, mixed-content

I have a page which sometimes sends command to network printer (http://192.168.1.50/Print) and it prints fine. I am planning to use https on that page. Everything works fine apart from the print function as it blocks the request to printer for not being https. I changed all links and other requests to https but not sure how to solve this bit? I am using Star Webprnt printer.

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to resolve it @James?